# Why are no parentheses needed when using the new keyword?

Tags: c#

If I want to get a list of all files in a certain directory, I can type something like:

```
var files = (new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp")).GetFiles();
```

However, the following also works (note the lack of parentheses before the "new" keyword):

```
var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp").GetFiles();
```

Why is this allowed to happen? Statements like:

```
2 + 4 * 3   and   (2 + 4) * 3
```

will resolve to 14 and 18, respectively, because of the parentheses.

It seems like my code example would be analogous to calling the ".GetFiles()" method on the static version of the DirectoryInfo object (because of the lack of the "new" keyword), where the parentheses combined with the "new" keyword make it explicit that I'm using an instance of the DirectoryInfo object.

i.e.:

```
2   +  4               * 3
new    DirectoryInfo()   .GetFiles()
```

vs:

```
(2   +  4              ) * 3
(new    DirectoryInfo())   .GetFiles()
```

Is there a simple explanation for why this is the case? Isn't it more work for the C# lexer to deal with both cases (with/without parentheses)? Is my analogy flawed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the article on MSDN regarding precedence:   [7.2.1](https://web.archive.org/web/20170207042906/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323(v=vs.71).aspx)

Since all non-assignment binary operators are left associative, the equally precedent `new` and `.` operators are evaluated left to right.

Thus, in the expression given, the object is instantiated before its method is called.  Also--`new` has equial precedence, so it consumes the type identifier (left to right) before the `.` could get it.

Answer (score 9):

> **Note:** This answer has a lot of expressions which are equivalent to each other. Rather than keep them inline or break them out into two separate lines, I've adopted a shorthand of `<==>` to mean "is equivalent to". So
>
> ```
> foo   <==>   bar
> ```
>
> should be read as "the expression `foo` is equivalent to the expression `bar`".

What you're talking about is *precedence*. `*` has a higher precedence than the binary `+` operator, so it "binds its operands" more tightly. So:

```
 x * y + z   <==>   (x * y) + z
```

Both `new` and the "dot" part are *primary* expressions, and they have the same precedence.
When two forms have the same precedence, *associativity* get involved. The C# spec isn't actually terribly clear here when it comes to the `new` operator, but the `.` operator is a binary operator, and all binary operators are deemed to be *left-associative*. In other words:

```
x.y.z   <==>   (x.y).z
```

As another example, `*` and `/` have the same precedence, so:

```
x * y / z   <==>   (x * y) / z
x / y * z   <==>   (x / y) * z
```

Therefore:

```
new DirectoryInfo(x).GetFiles()   <==>   (new DirectoryInfo()).GetFiles()
```

All of this is somewhat separate from evaluation order, which is *always* left to right. For example, in the expression `x + y * z`, the higher precedence of `*` means that:

```
x + y * z   <==>   x + (y * z)
```

... but it's still `x` which is evaluated first, then `y`, then `z`, then the multiplication, then finally the addition. As normal, [Eric Lippert writes extremely well on this topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

The syntax to call a static method is `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` and not `DirectoryInfo(...).GetFiles()`, so I'm not sure how there could be a conflict between those two interpretations.

Either way, your example with the numeric expression would multiply by 3 first because multiplication has higher precedence than addition or subtraction. All the parenthesis do is allow you to override the default precedence.

Even if the syntax was the same to call the static method, in the case you asked about, the default precedence would still cause that to work as expected without the parentheses.

Comment: that is what i was trying to say, but much more eloquent.

Comment: No, it's not about *ordering* - it's about *precedence*. They're not the same thing. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet  YES!   Where did the myth that the semantics matter come from?

Comment: @JonSkeet: No, they're not the same thing. But precedence does indeed affect evaluation ordering, and that seemed relevant to how the question was phrased.

Comment: @JonathanWood: Why confuse things by bringing in evaluation order though, when it's precedence and associativity which are important? Despite the fact that `*` has higher precedence than `+`, in the expression `x + y * z` it's still `x` that's evaluated first. I think it's worth being clear about the distinction. (I had to edit my own answer to try to clarify it - I realize it's hard - but it's worth doing...)

Comment: I didn't address precedence because the question seemed to only be asking about the associative nature of the parenthesis in terms of mathematics vs syntax. Which is why I liked Jonathan's answer better than mine. It mentioned both.

Answer (score 2):

You can't `new` a return value, so the compiler knows to put the new with the initialized type, and run the method on the new instance.

```
(new A()).Foo() // Makes sense! sort of...
new (A().Foo()) // Makes absolute no sense.

(1 + 4) * 10 // Makes sense
1 + (4 * 10) // Also makes sense
```

There is a different between the logic of how things work together between numbers and the C# keywords.

Comment: I am sorry, this is not true.  The parsing of expressions is done based on operator precedence, not semantics.  It is actually due to the left to right evalution of the equally precident non-assignment binary operators.   `.` is a binary operator.   And `new` has equal precidence with it.

Comment: I doubt that the compiler is even needed, the syntax is already unambiguous. And `new (A().Foo())` can make sense.

Comment: But in the `new` and `.` case, they are both with the same precedence, so they are evaluated from left to right. This isn't the case with numbers, and I was showing the difference.

Comment: @YoryeNathan I apologize, I didn't mean to.  The grammar of expressions can be quite subtle, especially in a precedence grammar like C# rather than one like our old old friend (if you are old like me) Pascal, where the formal syntax determined the bindings of the operator.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ One can always ask: "But, if C# syntax was so that you write the method and parameters before the dot, and the instance on which you operate after, it would be all messed up, but I bet that something would've taken care of that, Right?", So I was going straight there, because things aren't just blindly left-to-right, but there is logic into it.

Answer (score 1):

Your analogy is fine for order of operations in mathematics. But syntactically using new says to the compiler to be ready for a 'new' instance of a class. Parenthesis or not, you have a new instance of that class by using the keyword new.